# I am getting "Function not found: day at [5:84]"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT   field_3103,
         Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN field_3103 >=     Date(Extract(year FROM field_3103), Extract(month FROM field_3103), 1)
                  AND      field_3103 <= Date( Extract(year FROM field_3103), Extract(month FROM field_3103), Day(Last_day(field_3103))) THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
         END) AS new_listings,
         Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN field_3102 >=     Date(Extract(year FROM field_3102), Extract(month FROM field_3102), 1)
                  AND      field_3102 <= Date(Extract(year FROM field_3102), Extract(month FROM field_3102), Day(Last_day(field_3102))) THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
         END) AS sold_listings
FROM     winter-agility-327715.properties_dataset.final_table
GROUP BY 1
```

This query results in the following error message:

> "Function not found: day at [5:84]"

The syntax error in my SQL is also underlined as can be seen in this screen shot: [image]

Comment: The message tells you "function not found: day". It even tells you exactly in which position the error is and highlights it in your code. So what do you guess the error is? There simply is no function called `DAY` in Google BigQuery. I am dumbfounded you are coming here, when the error is so obvious. Date functions in Google BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=de

Comment: ... or don't you have a question? Did you only want to show us what happens when you put a function in your SQL that you invented yourself? In case you do have a question: What exactly do you want to know from us that you haven't been able to find out yourself?

Comment: Please describe what your goal with this query is. All case will return 1. In first part of the case statement you look that the date is at or after the 1st day of the month. This is always true. (Hint: use `date_trunc(field_3103,month)` to obatin the 1st of a month. The 2nd part of the case does not work, because `day` is not a BigQuery function; use `Extract(day from Last_day(field_3103))`  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Thorsten and @Samuel, you are getting this error as there is no `DAY` function in BigQuery.
If you want to extract day you can use the following syntax:

`EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_expression)`

For more information on Date functions in BigQuery refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=de).